# General vs specific Android version tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Just now I noticed that there were 6 questions tagged with [5.1.1-lolipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.1.1-lolipop). In addition to the typo, most of the tagged questions don't seem related to 5.1.1 specifically:

- [What is the best way to root a 2012 Nexus 7 running 5.1.1 Lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111885/what-is-the-best-way-to-root-a-2012-nexus-7-running-5-1-1-lollipop)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112535/can-you-uninstall-lollipop
- [Show sensitive notification content when at trusted place](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/show-sensitive-notification-content-when-at-trusted-place)
- [What is this icon?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/what-is-this-icon)
- [How to use face unlock in Sony Xperia Z2 running Cyanogemod 12?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112112/how-to-use-face-unlock-in-sony-xperia-z2-running-cyanogemod-12)
- [Failed updating and uninstalling app with ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111315/failed-updating-and-uninstalling-app-with-adb)

I have cleaned-up those questions:

- Renamed the tag to [5.1.1-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.1.1-lollipop) for related questions
- Removed the tag on questions which were not version-dependent
- **Replaced the tag with [5.0-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.0-lollipop) for general Lollipop-related question.**

Now, when I read the excerpt for [5.0-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.0-lollipop)

> Android 5.0 is the tenth publicly named Android release, and debuted with the Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 in November of 2014. Please only use this tag if you feel your question is specific to Android 5.0.

Before the existence of 5.1 and 5.1.1, the excerpt reads okay; Lollipop-related questions will be tagged with that since there's only 1 suitable tag. But after the release of 5.1 and 5.1.1, newcomers are confused how to tag their questions ([although, that's their fault for not reading help/meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-can-i-tag-my-question-in-the-most-effective-way), but still tolerable). But then, I see the problem: currently, it seems that there's no tag for general Android version (e.g. general Lollipop feature/issue). There is [lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) which is synonymized to [5.0-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.0-lollipop) though.

So, the question is: what can we do to reduce the mistag? What should we do to the question that is for general Android version (e.g. general Lollipop problems)?

Also possibly related: [Do we really need "4.4.2-kitkat"?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/do-we-really-need-4-4-2-kitkat)

Comment: I can see a split for 5.0 vs 5.1, but not 5.1.1. I've merged the latter two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that [lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lollipop) is already synonymized to [5.0-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.0-lollipop), I propose that tag to be the general Lollipop version. In addition to this, we should make it clear on the tag excerpt, perhaps by adding:

> Android 5.0 is the tenth publicly named Android release, and debuted with the Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 in November of 2014. Please only use this tag if you feel your question is specific to Android 5.0 **or general Android Lollipop**.

Then, on other tags like [5.1-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.1-lollipop), add similar info for the excerpt:

> Android 5.1 is an incremental update in the "Lollipop" version series. Please only use this tag if you feel your question is specific to Android 5.1. **For general Lollipop feature/issue, please use [5.0-lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/5.0-lollipop) instead**.

Or perhaps we can follow [4.1-jelly-bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.1-jelly-bean) approach:

> The version of Android after 4.0.x (Ice Cream Sandwich) in the Android version sequence. Please only use this tag if your question specifically pertains to Jelly Bean and its features.

The follow-up is to retag & clean-up the questions which should use general version instead of specific version tag.